Custom class methods missing from object at runtime
I'm extending Map to create an object for handling data consistantly.  However, my custom methods aren't showing up at runtime:
class DataMap extends Map {
  constructor(...args:any[]) {
    super(...args)
  }
  foo(): void {
    console.log('Foo called...')
  }

  getItems() : object[] {
    return Array.from(this.values())
  }
  static fromValues(values:object[], key:string='id') : DataMap {
    return new DataMap(values.map((_:any) => {
      return [_[key], _]
    }))
  }
  update(map:DataMap){
    const self = this;
    map.forEach((value, key)=>{
      self.set(key, value);
    })
  }
  updateFromList(values:Array<any>, key:string='id'){
    const self = this;
    values.forEach((_:any)=>{
      self.set(_[key], _)
    })
  }
}


export const useTenantStore = defineStore("tenant", () => {
    
  // Fetch Data
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  const dataStore = useDataStore()
  const client = generateClient<Schema>()
  
  const tenants = ref<DataMap>(new DataMap())
  async function _fetchTenantsByCompany(
    company:Company
  ) : Promise<void> {
    // fetch by company id
    const {data: _tenants, errors} = await client.models.Tenant.list({
        selectionSet: [
        'id','owner_id','first_name', 'last_name', 'business_name', 'is_business',
        'is_active', 'leases.*', 'transactions.*', 'leases.units.*', 
        'transactions.transaction_attributions.*'
        ],
        filter: {
        company_id: {
            eq: company.id
        }
        },
        authMode: 'userPool'
    })
    // tenants.value = _tenants as unknown as Array<FullTenant>
    console.log('map size: ', tenants.value.size) // this works
    tenants.value.foo()  // this throws TypeError: tenants.value.foo is not a function
    tenants.value.updateFromList(_tenants) // this throws TypeError: tenants.value.updateFromList is not a function
  }

  async function load_tenants_by_company(
    force_refresh:Boolean=false
  ) : Promise<void> {
    if (!dataStore.company) {
        await watch_for_dependancy_loaded(()=>dataStore.company, _fetchTenantsByCompany)
    } else if (dataStore.company || force_refresh) {
        await _fetchTenantsByCompany(dataStore.company)
    }
  }

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

What am I missing here?

I tried running your TypeScript code and doing some tests. And I can both see and use your custom methods at runtime. The only reason I could imagine it not working for you is that your build step isn't properly transpiling your TypeScript to JavaScript. Perhaps this is because you have an error in your code: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556) on line 3? Alternatively you may have messed up your tsconfig.json?

